# Url.Action route parameters not rendered as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, routes

I have a problem with building url redirection by values taken from model passed to Razor view in my MVC app.

My href attribute of anchor tag looks like below (list of  tags generated by foreach loop):

```
@Url.Action(item.Action, item.Controller, new RouteValueDictionary(new { parameter= item.ActionParameter }
```

Controller has routing defined by attributes:

```
    [RoutePrefix("SampleController")]
    public class ChartController : Controller
    {
        [Route("MyActionName/{parameter}")]
        public ActionResult SampleAction(string parameter) {}
    }
```

The rendered url passes parameter as query parameter: ?parameter=value. How to change that to achieve something like: /SampleController/MyActionName/ParameterValue??

I will be grateful for your help

Regards,
Jacek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try  this syntax

```
@Url.Action(item.Action, item.Controller, new { id= item.ActionParameter })
```

Comment: Do you still have   the same Url   --  /SampleController/MyActionName?Parameter=value ???

Comment: Ooo I see! The parameter name is "id" in your syntax. At first I have tried with 
new { parameter = item.ActionParameter } like in the route definition. It works, thank you!